# HDFS to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, etl, hdfs

We need a process in place to pull data from [Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS)](http://hadoop.apache.org/hdfs/) to a relational DB (PostgreSQL) on a regular basis. We will need to transfer several million records per hour and I am looking for the best industry standards to move data out of HDFS. Does any one have any suggestions?
The idea is for a web app to interact with PostgreSQL which will have aggregated data.

Answer (score 3):

[Sqoop](http://sqoop.apache.org/) is built for the purpose of moving data between relational data stores and Hadoop. Specifically, you want [sqoop-export](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_export_literal).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Donald! But I thought sqoop didn't support data export into PostgreSQL at this time.